# How does this work: using a for loop to find the largest number in an array

Tags: javascript

Well, I like to not just memorize blocks of code, but to understand them, so that I can create them myself. Why does this work? I don't understand. If someone can explain it to me, I'd be most grateful. To me it looks like: "If the array index (position in the array) is greater than 0, 0 = the array index," and how that would magically tell me the highest number in the array I haven't a single clue. I've tried searching for an answer on this but without luck. Here's an example of the code, thanks in advance:

```
var array = [3, 4, 5, 21.15, 21, 9];
var largest = 0;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);​
```

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding one point. `array[i]` returns the value at the position `i` in the array. So it compares the number at the `i`position with the current largest number. Once the array is all over, the largest number is in the variable largest.

Comment: I suggest you use `Math.max(...array)` it's a lot less code and it is a lot easier to understand to learn more about how to use the `...` search up Spread Syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `largest = array[i];` does NOT mean `0 = array[i]` as you believe. `largest` is a *variable*, so each time you get to the line `largest = array[i];` you are *changing* the value of `largest` to be the current `array[i]`.

This is why you get the max of the array at the end.

An example: `a = [1, 3, 7, 2]`

You initialize `largest = 0`. The, for each element of the array you do the following:

```
largest < 1? yes, so largest = 1
largest < 3? yes, so largest = 3
largest < 7? yes, so largest = 7
largest < 2? no, so do nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = [3, 4, 5, 21.15, 21, 9];
var largest = 0;

    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]>largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```

---

```
Iteration 1:
Check if array[0] i.e. 3 is greater than 0 => True : largest = 3

Iteration 2:
Check if array[1] i.e. 4 is greater than 3 => True : largest = 4

Iteration 3:
Check if array[2] i.e. 5 is greater than 4 => True : largest = 5

Iteration 4:
Check if array[3] i.e. 21.25 is greater than 5 => True : largest = 21.25

Iteration 5:
Check if array[4] i.e. 21 is greater than 21.25 => False: largest = 21.25

Iteration 6:
Check if array[5] i.e. 9 is greater than 21.25 => False: largest = 21.25
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 largest = array[i]; //Assign whatever is at the position 'i' in the array
                     //to the variable 'largest'

 if (array[i]>largest) // See if the value at the position 'i' in the array
                        //is greater than what is contained in the variable 'largest'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a another `console.log` statement and it will be clearer.

```
var array = [3, 4, 5, 21.15, 21, 9];
var largest = 0;

    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]>largest) {
        console.log(largest + " " + array[i]);
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
console.log(largest);
```

Which gives the output

> 0 3
>
> 3 4
>
> 4 5
>
> 5 21.15
>
> 21.15

If `array[i]` is greater than the current value of `largest`, the value of `largest` is overwritten by `array[i]`. It loops through the array, making the comparison each time.

Answer (score 0):

> how that would magically tell me the highest number in the array

It won't.  Because of

```
var largest = 0;
```

if the largest value in the array is negative, then it will spuriously report `0` as the largest value.  For example, if `var array = [-3, -4, -5, -21.15, -21, -9];` then `largest` will be `0` at the end of the loop, not `-3`.

The below should do better, and will return `undefined` if there are no values that are meaningfully comparable to numbers in the array.

```
var greatestIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; ++i) {
  if (greatestIndex >= 0 ? array[i] > array[greatestIndex] : array[i] >= -Infinity) {
    greatestIndex = i;
  }
}
return greatestIndex >= 0 ? array[greatestIndex] : undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a variable "maxNumber" to be initially equal to the lowest possible number and run a "for loop" where you check if every next number in the string is higher than the initial value and then overright the current value of the input over the initial value it will eventually run through the array by checking every current number with the previous one and log the highest number.

```
function solve(input) {
    let count = +input.shift();
    let maxNumber = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

    for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        let number = +input.shift();
        if (number > minNumber) {
            mmaxNumber = number;
        }
    }
console.log(maxNumber);
}
```